# How to escape a SQL query with colon in Jquery mobile?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm making a mobile web and tried sending a query to my server database with the following code:

```
   $user="root";
   $pass="";
   $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=the_restaurant', $user, $pass);
   $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * from table_availability where table_number= :table');
   $statement->execute(array(':table' => $table_number));
   // Set the fetch mode
   $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    while($row = $stmt->fetch())
       {
         echo "<tr class=\"clickable\" data-url=\"{orders.php}\"><td><p>" . $row['dish_name']. "</p></td>";
         echo "<td><p>" . $row['quantity']. "</p></td>";
         echo "<td><p>" . $row['price']. "</p></td>";
         echo "<td><p>" . $row['ewt']. "</p></td></tr>";
       }
```

this query can be executed but my background image disappeared. I traced it and the culprit was the colon in the statement. Is there anyway I can get rid of this problem? Or any alternative? I need my background for my UI. I already tried with backslash but still the same:

```
   $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * from table_availability where table_number= \\:table');
```

I'm using jQuery mobile. Any idea?

Comment: How is the image related to the query? Explain more context. And how do you send the query to your php script? The colon of the named placeholder wouldn't need extraneous escaping by itself.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use prepared statement syntax in a plain query. That doesn't make sense. Escaping certainly won't help. You need to either prepare and execute a statement or pass an actual value.

Comment: Are you using PDO, ZEND, or What?

Comment: I'm using PDO and I'm new to it. The image is not part of the query, its outside the query. I meant the background image of my site, it looks like the background image is disabled if I put colon in the statement.

Comment: Question is really confusing since you don't send queries to server, you send data that gets used to create queries. WHat is being sent and where is the code that receives it?

Comment: I updated the codes. I have no problem with the query, the query works and is received by the server. The problem is the colon in the query because it disables the background image of the current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) it doesn't seem like you should be using `query` for parameterized queries:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->execute(array(150, 'red'));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thank you soo much! You're a genius - this is what i meant, an alternative to avoid the colon.

Answer (score 0):

this is just a PHP.net example of how to use prepared statement, the way that you want. Please accommodate this example with your needs

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

// insert another row with different values
$name = 'two';
$value = 2;
$stmt->execute();
?>
```